# How to trigger a function just before session timeout in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, session

I want to call a method that keeps tracking of check in and checkout for user activity. I'm setting session timeout to expire the session, but before session timeouts, i want to store the user activity. Therefore I'm trying to call a method inside javascript using ajax to run that method just before the session expires. Unfortunately the method is not running. Below is my code!

**Admin.Master.cs**

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    if (!this.IsPostBack)
                    {
                        Session["Reset"] = true;
                        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.Config");
                        SessionStateSection section = (SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
                        int timeout = (int)section.Timeout.TotalMinutes * 1000 * 60;
                        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SessionAlert", "SessionExpireAlert(" + timeout + ");", true);
                    }
    }

 [WebMethod]
        public void logout_timeout() //This method i have to run
        {
}
```

**Admin.Master**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function SessionExpireAlert(timeout)
        {
            debugger
            var seconds = timeout / 1000;
            document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
            document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
            setInterval(function () {
                seconds--;
                document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
                document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function ()
            {

                //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Admin.Master/logout_timeout",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: OnError
                });
                $find("mpeTimeout").show();
            }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = "Login.aspx";

                //$.ajax(
                //                  {
                //                      type: "POST",
                //                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //                      url: "Case.aspx/removeTrans",
                //                      data: "{ 'DelData':'" + transId + "'}",
                //                      success: function (result) { window.location.reload(true); console.log("successful!"); }
                //                  })



            }, timeout);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Move logout_timeout function to xxxx.aspx and call Ajax URL  "xxxx.aspx/logout_timeout" instead.

Comment: Well in that case, I've used other method in other xxxx.aspx but that didn't run also.

Comment: Firstly, does SessionExpireAlert was called?

Comment: Yes that is called

Comment: I doubt your js code is not well-formed. Could you please comment all code except $ajax call?

Comment: Commented complete JavaScript function except ajax call. The method didn't run yet.